# Loose focus vnc viewer issue

Tags: wpf, vnc

The question is already asked in below link

[i can't see a context menu of WPF windows app through VNC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990153/i-cant-see-a-context-menu-of-wpf-windows-app-through-vnc)

But my requirements are slightly differ from it.

When I run my application in vnc viewer, and click on start menu from vnc toolbar and back to my application, right click on textbox does not show context menu like, copy, paste, cut.

Then, when i go task manager, right click on my application, and do "bring to front", then everything is working fine.

So I just want to know what is happening while clicking on vnc toolbar button, will take my application's focus back.

Thanks,
Rajnikant

Comment: Sorry, this place is for _programming questions_. You might want to ask your question over at the `SuperUser` place, you will find the link at the bottom of this page.

Comment: thnx mate for your information