# Is it possible to set the WPF RenderMode in the XAML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml

I have built a GUI with XAML and Powershell. The problem is that certain visual elements such as dropdown menus are not visible when viewing the application remotely via VNC.

My search led me to this piece of code that I am supposed to run in the OnLoad method of the window to force the RenderMethod to SoftwareOnly:

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

However, this is C#. My code-behind is Powershell.

So is there a way to either do this in Powershell, or to set the RenderMethod of the Windows in the XAML file?

The real reason I'm asking this question is because the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990153/i-cant-see-a-context-menu-of-wpf-windows-app-through-vnc) do not work for me. The alpha-blending option simply does not exist in recent versions of UVNC.

Comment: Never used Powershell, but static properties should be settable like this: `[System.Windows.Media.RenderOptions]::ProcessRenderMode = ...`

Comment: Right, turns out I can use [System.Windows.Media.RenderOptions]::ProcessRenderMode = "SoftwareOnly". Too bad that doesn't solve my original issue.